# What would be the best visually appealing power BI chart/graph to compare numbers with huge differences?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

I need to compare Year Month values somehow next to each other.
But the difference is so big that it is not very visually appealing.
I tried to find a good chart to display those, but so far no success.

Any recommendation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to share the same axis as you have in your image, you could switch the scale to logarithmic instead of linear. Otherwise, you could try putting them on separate axes so they scale independently.

Another option would be to normalize them somehow. If one set were monthly, then you could multiply it by 12 to "annualize" it.